# Step is always 0 when using tf.estimator.Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I have been trying to learn the layers and estimators framework that was recently moved from contrib to main API. I ran into a rather strange problem. I wrote a simple autoencoder for MNIST, but somehow, when I train it keeps saying I am at step 0 even though the loss value is decreasing, so I guess the model is getting trained. Of course, since it is not counting steps, it is not saving the checkpoints and it is not saving any summaries either. Not sure what I am doing wrong and all the docs point to the old "tf.contrib.learn" framework and a lot of APIs there seem to be marked as deprecated. How do I make this work? Here is my code:

```
def encoder(x):
    l1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 256, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='encode1')
    l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 128, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='encode2')
    return l2

def decoder(x):
    l1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 256, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='decode1')
    l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 784, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='decode2')
    return l2

def loss(labels, preds):
    return tf.losses.huber_loss(labels, preds)

def train(loss):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    return optimizer.minimize(loss)

def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    _encoder = encoder(features)
    _decoder = decoder(_encoder)
    _loss = loss(labels, _decoder)
    _train = train(_loss)
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                      predictions=_decoder,
                                      loss=_loss,
                                      train_op=_train)

data = input_data.read_data_sets(".", one_hot=True)
display.clear_output()
# remove current log dir
shutil.rmtree('logs', ignore_errors=True)

def input_fn():
    if data.train.epochs_completed <= 10:
        features, labels = data.train.next_batch(100)
        return tf.constant(features), tf.constant(features)
    raise StopIteration

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn, "logs")
estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn)
```

And here is some sample output

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': 'logs', '_tf_random_seed': 1, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_session_config': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000}
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into logs/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0505481, step = 0
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00319921, step = 0 (1.125 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00277268, step = 0 (1.094 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00275822, step = 0 (1.106 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00275116, step = 0 (1.069 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00275018, step = 0 (1.130 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00274921, step = 0 (1.161 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00274908, step = 0 (1.140 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00274683, step = 0 (1.105 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00274397, step = 0 (1.111 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `training op` you need to set the `global_step` parameter, which is the step counter that gets incremented for each model training run. So change to :

```
optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
```

Comment: Thank you. It almost seems like this is something that would be taken care of internally, after all, the train op is defined, so why cannot it count the number of times it runs.

Comment: Even i was surprised why it was not done internally. But then this guide mentions how to define the training op: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/extend/estimators#defining_loss

Comment: Yeah, I am kinda hoping these things will clean up in 1.3. 1.2 seems to have a lot of confusion between the core tensorflow APIs and tf.contrib.learn APIs.

Comment: I have posted another couple of questions about working with estimator framework. Can you take a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469356/number-of-steps-doesnt-match-when-using-tf-estimator-estimator

Comment: Sure, ill have a look

Comment: Looks like they have moved from monitors to hooks and there i could not find a validation hook, i could find a loogingTensorHook, which is a straightforward call.