# Number of steps doesn't match when using tf.estimator.Estimator

Tags: tensorflow

I am figuring out the TensorFlow estimator framework. I finally have code for a model that trains. I am using a simple MNIST autoencoder for my tests. I have two questions. The first question is why the number of steps reported by training is different from the number of steps I specify in estimator train() method? The second one is how to use training hooks to do things like periodic evaluations, loss output every X steps etc? The docs seem to say to use training hooks, but I cannot seem to find any actual examples of how to use these.

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import time
import shutil
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from IPython import display
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

data = input_data.read_data_sets('.')
display.clear_output()

def _model_fn(features, labels, mode=None, params=None):
    # define inputs
    image = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('images', shape=(784, ))
    inputs = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, [image, ])
    # encoder
    e1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    e2 = tf.layers.dense(e1, 256, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # decoder
    d1 = tf.layers.dense(e2, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    model = tf.layers.dense(d1, 784, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # training ops
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, model)
    train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          loss=loss,
                                          train_op=train)

_train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({'images': data.train.images},
                                                     y=np.array(data.train.images),
                                                     batch_size=100,
                                                     shuffle=True)

shutil.rmtree("logs", ignore_errors=True)
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(_model_fn, 
                                   model_dir="logs", 
                                   config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_steps=1000),
                                   params={})
estimator.train(_train_input_fn, steps=1000)
```

And here is the output I get (notice how training stops at 550 steps where the code explicitely calls for a 1000)

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_task_type': None, '_task_id': 0, '_cluster_spec': <tensorflow.python.training.server_lib.ClusterSpec object at 0x12b9fa630>, '_master': '', '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_environment': 'local', '_is_chief': True, '_evaluation_master': '', '_tf_config': gpu_options {
  per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1
}
, '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_secs': None, '_session_config': None, '_save_checkpoints_steps': 1000, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_model_dir': 'logs'}
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 1 into logs/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.102862, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 41.8119
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0191228, step = 101 (2.393 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 39.9923
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0141014, step = 201 (2.500 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 40.9806
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0116138, step = 301 (2.440 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 40.0043
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00998991, step = 401 (2.500 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 39.2571
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0124132, step = 501 (2.548 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 550 into logs/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 0.00940801.

<tensorflow.python.estimator.estimator.Estimator at 0x12b9fa780>
```

**Update #1** I found the answer to the first question. The reason training stopped at step 550 was because numpy_input_fn() defaults to num_epochs=1. I am still looking for help with training hooks though.

Comment: For periodic validation, I'd go with [ValidationMonitor](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/monitors#configuring_a_validationmonitor_for_streaming_evaluation) for the moment. It is deprecated because it's using an older parent class, so you may get warnings, but there is no SessionRunHook-based replacement for ValidationMonitor yet. Feel free to add some emojis [to the bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7669).

Comment: It seems that it should be possible to subclass SessionRunHook and make it run ops you want at certain steps by cut/pasting some code from StepCounterHook class implementation. I think I am going to go with that, but I wish things were documented better and I wish existing subclasses for session hook were more useful.

Comment: Yes, things could certainly be improved. If you build something you like, it could make a nice pull request... you may want to ping @ispirmustafa to coordinate.

Comment: First, will try to implement my own periodic evaluation and post it as an answer here.

Comment: @MadWombat Did you manage to make it work? If so, could you answer your question with your results?

Comment: @Maxime No, I have not. I see a few ways of doing it, but real work got in the way. I will update once I have something working. Also, it seems that the default "log a message every 100 steps" hook is hard-coded and cannot be taken out or altered. This is really annoying and I intend to file a bug with TF.

Answer (score 2):

The estimator can be run in 3 modes.

1. Train
2. evaluate
3. predict

your current code is only configured to run in training mode. If you want to include evaluation step then you have to make some changes into the model function first :

```
def _model_fn(features, labels, mode=None, params=None):
    # define inputs
    image = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('images', shape=(784, ))
    inputs = tf.feature_column.input_layer(features, [image, ])
    # encoder
    e1 = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    e2 = tf.layers.dense(e1, 256, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # decoder
    d1 = tf.layers.dense(e2, 512, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    model = tf.layers.dense(d1, 784, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    # training ops
    loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, model)
    train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode,
                                          loss=loss,
                                          train_op=train)

    prec, prec_update_op = tf.metrics.precision(labels=labels,predictions=model), name='precision_op')
    recall, recall_update_op = tf.metrics.recall(labels=labels, predictions=model, name='recall_op')

    metrics={'recall':(recall, recall_update_op), \
               'precision':(prec, prec_update_op)}

    if mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
          return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, loss=loss, eval_metric_ops=metrics)
```

Now to do evaluation and print loss output every 10 steps.

```
configuration = tf.estimator.RunConfig(
  model_dir = 'logs',
  keep_checkpoint_max=5,
  save_checkpoints_steps=1500,
  log_step_count_steps=10)  # set the frequency of logging steps for loss function

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = _model_fn, params = {}, config=configuration)

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=_train_input_fn, steps=5000) 
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=_train_input_fn, steps=100, throttle_secs=600)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(classifier, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Note:

1. after every new checkpoint is saved (i.e at every 1500 step), evaluation is run for 100 steps and then training resumes.
2. The **log_step_count_steps** prints loss output every X steps.
3. The argument **throttle_secs** defines the minimum number of seconds between two consecutive evaluation steps. If a new checkpoint is stored before this number of seconds then evaluation is skipped.

The above will train and evaluate on the same dataset, if you want it to be done on a different dataset, then pass it's(the dataset's) suitable input function to the argument **input_fn** at **tf.estimator.EvalSpec**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the you've gone through all of your data by 550 steps.
numpy_input_fn default 'num_epochs' parameter is 1 so you only get to run your data once.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/inputs/numpy_input_fn

Therefore, you should either set num_epochs to None to satisfy your steps.